# Separating numbers from a string of which numbers are separated by a $ symbol?

Tags: python, regex

I have taken a string in which numbers will end with commas `,` The program is as shown below:

```
import re 
s = 'natraj 12 dozen $100.25, camlin 10 box $1250.50,' 
lis = re.split('\s*\$\s*|\s*\,\s*', s)[:-1] 
print(lis)
description = lis[0::2] 
amount = lis[1::2] 
print(description) 
print(amount)
```

**Output:**

```
description = ['natraj 12 dozen','camlin 10 box'] and
amount = ['100.25',1250.50']
```

(`amount` list should not contain $ sign)

Now I want same output as above: but **now** the input string **does not** contain **commas**

```
s = 'natraj 12 dozen $100.25 camlin 10 box $1250.50'
```

Comment: Have you tried modifying the regular expression to not require the comma?

Comment: So you want to separate out all the prices? What's your desired output here?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: desired out put is a seperate list for price as 100.25,1250.50, and seperate list for description as natraj 12 dozen ,camlin 10 box

Comment: @IqbalHawre please **edit the question** to show inputs and expected and actual outputs (i.e. what your code *does*, and what you *want it to do*). You should also consider giving your variables more helpful names (what are `lis1` and `lis2` supposed to hold?)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve that goal.  Some:

1. Strip punctuation
2. make the comma optional (my favorite)
3. parse manually, grabbing clusters of [0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}

Number 2 above is really easy given your example .. just add `?` (previous RE clause optional) to the comma:

```
lis=re.split('\s*\$\s*|\s*\,?\s*', s)[:-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for ur time and effort paul.....but ur code leads to output as : ['natraj',' dozen ',' camlin ','box'] and another list as ['12',100.25,10] What i want is : first list as .....['natraj 12 dozen ',' camlin 10 box '] and second list as ['100.25',' 1250.50']

Comment: Just assemble the non-currency tokens into the string, and the currency tokens into a list.  You should be able to find that easily enough by the "$" at the front.  Come to think of it, you could just split on spaces and iterate through the tokens -- no regex needed.

Comment: can't we read all numbers after $ sign till next alphabet or end of string

Comment: .....description=re.split('\d*\$\d*', s)[:-1].....this will give rite output for description but i am not able to get output for amount

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex to seperate number and description part,

```
(?P<Numbers>\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?,)|(?P<Description>\w+(?: \w+)*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/8)

Remove comma from the captured group if you don't want it.

```
(?P<Numbers>\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(?P<Description>\w+(?: \w+)*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/9)

Comment: avinash ji please ....... python code .....u r close to solution... but give me python code ...i m dumb in regex

Comment: @IqbalHawre did you want the output in list?

Comment: .....description=re.split('\d*\$\d*', s)[:-1].....this will give rite output for description but i am not able to get output for amount

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the characters of the string in a list, then use the .delete function to remove the comma from the list, and return the list in your output. Hopes this helps.:). \

```
    list_of_s = [s]
    list_of_s.delete(',')
```